# How develop an screen scrapping for desktop Application like a uipath, power automate or Automation Anywhere

Tags: desktop-application

What knowledge do I need and how difficult is it to develop ?

What languaje is better for this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for desktop automation, most RPA tools leverage the following technologies:
for windows desktop applications:
Microsoft UIA or MSAA, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-and-microsoft-active-accessibility

for java application:
Java access bridge

for SAP windows GUI: leverage SAP autoscripting features
for remoting automation, such as RDP or citrix, need writing yourself, leverage the RDP or citrix protocol to do communication, then on remoting side, can still use UIA， MSAA， Java access bridge to do desktop automation.

You can also base on the python library beyond those automation technology to develop screen scrapping tools. such as
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium